# Empower maximized intensified spell. How do they all stack

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, metamagic

If I have a spell that has all 3 of these metamagics applied, how do they stack?

Shocking grasp for example. 5d6, does it turn into 10d6 from intense, then is maximized for 60+5d6 (empowered)

Or are they all applied more separately, 30 + 5d6 intensified, +5d6 empowered?

Which is the correct way to apply these?

Comment: I have no idea how that happened. Thats odd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Officially, you roll 10d6, halve it, and add that to 60

The combination of maximized and empowered is detailed (and explicitly allowed) by text in the [maximize spell](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Maximize%20Spell) feat

> An empowered, maximized spell gains the separate benefits of each feat: the maximum result plus half the **normally** rolled result.

Empowered Maximized Intensified Shocking Grasp does 60 + (10d6/2) damage.

Empowered increases the 'normal' rolls by 50%, maximized ensures that all dice 'unrolled' dice are max (6 in this case), and intensified allows you to roll more dice (for both purposes). So you get <strike>five</strike> ten <strike>d6</strike> times 6 = 60 + (10d6/2)

**Despite this, I would recommend GM's allow your thought of 60+5d6 for simplicity.**

Comment: I was just editing because I remembered that